# How to have a dynamic number of threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I would like to calculate a mathematic summation in c using threads. 
(∑x^i ,From 0 to N) Each threads should calculate each terms of the summation and finally in the main the program should sum all of them and print them. 
How should I make the number of threads dynamically?
Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <math.h>

pthread_t sadaf[10];
int i,a[10];
long int x,N;
int sum=0;
pthread_mutex_t mtx;

void *Myfun(void *tid)
{
    int *ThreadID=(int *)tid;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    printf("The thread with id of %d calculated x^i\n",*ThreadID);
    a[*ThreadID]=pow(x,*ThreadID);
    sum=sum+a[*ThreadID];
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

}

int main()
{
     int d[10] = {0};
     printf("->**************************************************************************<-\n");
     printf("This program will calculate the following function:\n-> ∑x^i ,From 0 to N \n");
     printf("->**************************************************************************<-\n");
     printf("Please enter x:\n");
     scanf("%ld",&x);
     printf("Please enter N:\n");
     scanf("%ld",&N);

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        d[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&sadaf[i],NULL,Myfun,(void *)&d[i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(sadaf[i],NULL);
    }


    printf("The sum is: %d\n",sum);

}
```

Comment: Your arrays (*all* of them) have space for ten elements. If you input an `N` that is equal to or larger than ten you will go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: One of those simple things to remember: If you have a hard coded array size you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: If you use a variable for your loops that is defined at file scope, you are definitely begging for trouble.

Comment: @Gerhardh: So in this way, how should I make the number of my threads dynamic?

Comment: @saeedtalaee,I was not referring to the threads but to vaiable `i` that you use as counter for your loop.
You cannot create unlimited number of threads as it depletes resources. You could just start 10 at a time and collect results. Then add these values up and start next round of 10 threads and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `d` array can hold 10 values, so if `N` is greater than 10, you have an out of bounds problem:

```
    int d[10] = {0};
    ...

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        d[i] = i;      // if i > 10 => you access out of bounds => problem
```

You have the same problem with other arrays too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how can I  have a dynamic number of threads! instead of defining it? Using a for is enough?

Comment: I mean what if a user enter a large number of threads! system is going to lock! what is a good constraint for number of pthreads?

Comment: The problem here is not the number of threads but because you access arrays out of bounds.  The simplest thing here is to replace all `x y[10]` by `x y[MAX_NB_OF_THREADS]`, put a `#define MAX_NB_OF_THREADS 30` (or whatever) and check if the user enters a number > MAX_NB_OF_THREADS and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 10 `pthreads` defined at the beginning.

```
pthread_t sadaf[10];
```

Creating more than 10 threads will cause the undefined behaviour.

Comment: Just a question, How to avoid that?